# Simplest JSF 2.0 application will not work

Tags: java, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I've never had such a problem getting the simplest stuff to work in Java EE 6.  I have an extremely basic project.  I've tried debugging.  Etc.  I don't know what to do.

Here is my bean.

```
@Named(value = "contactsBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ContactsBean implements Serializable {

   @EJB
   ContactsFacade contactsEJB;
   private List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();  

   public ContactsBean() {

   }

   public String next() {
       contacts = contactsEJB.findAll();        
       return "index";
   }

   /**
     * @return the contacts
   */
   public List<Contacts> getContacts() {
      return contacts;
   }

   /**
    * @param contacts the contacts to set
   */
   public void setContacts(List<Contacts> contacts) {
      this.contacts = contacts;
   }
}
```

Ok.  Pretty basic.

Here is my xhtml page.

```
 <ui:define name="content">

            <h:form>
                <h:dataTable value="#{contactsBean.contacts}" var="contacts">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                        </f:facet>    
                        <h:outputText value="#{contacts.name}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Street"/>
                        </f:facet>    
                        <h:outputText value="#{contacts.street}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="City"/>
                        </f:facet>    
                        <h:outputText value="#{contacts.city}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="State"/>
                        </f:facet>    
                        <h:outputText value="#{contacts.state}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Zip"/>
                        </f:facet>    
                        <h:outputText value="#{contacts.zip}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Country"/>
                        </f:facet>    
                        <h:outputText value="#{contacts.country}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Sent?"/>
                        </f:facet>    
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{contacts.sent}" />
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>


                <h:commandButton value="next &gt;" action="#{contactsBean.next}"/>     


            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
```

Ok when I hit the next button my list should populate.  At least it always did in Java EE 5 stuff.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I was trying to do a simple paginator but even that wouldn't work.  The model never gets updated.

What in the world is going on.  I tried it without an EJB and it didn't work either.

Comment: What container are you deploing into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason.

There are to different packages with SessionScoped annotations.

javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped and javax.faces.context.SessionScoped.

Since I'm using @Named(value = "contactsBean") injection I need to use javax.enterprise.  @ManagedBean(name = "contactsBean") goes with javax.faces.context.